# Probability of 1st marble being green, or 2nd being green?

Tags: probability, statistics

There is a bag with 3 green marbles, and 2 red marbles. What is the probability of the 1st marble being green OR the 2nd marble being green?

I first made use of the formula: P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A and B)

From this I found that: 
P(1st green) = 3/5

And that:
P(2nd green) = P(2nd green|1st green) + P(2nd green|1st red)

So: 
P(1st green or 2nd green) = (3/5) + (1/2) + (3/4) - (3/10) = 31/20

I know this is incorrect because the probability is greater than 1. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $$\begin{split}\text{P(2nd G)} =& \text{P(1st G and 2nd G) +P(1st R and 2nd G)} \\=& \left(\frac{3}{5}\times\frac{2}{4}\right)+\left(\frac{2}{5}\times\frac{3}{4}\right) \\=& \frac{3}{5}\end{split}$$ You got $\frac{5}{4}$!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression for the probability that the second is green is incorrect.  Indeed, the probability that any particular slot is green is $\frac 35$.

Specifically, you need to weight each term in your sum by the probability of being in that situation.  That is to say $$P(2nd\, green) = P(2nd\, green|1st \,green)\times P(first \;green) + P(2nd\, green|first\, red)\times P(first\,red)$$

Comment: Can you explain why this is the case?

Comment: This is the law of total probability.  You have chosen to divide the cases up according to the color of the first draw.  So, first consider the case "first draw green".  Ok, that has probability $\frac 35$.  Now, given that this event occurred, we also want the second one to be green.  That has (conditional) probability $\frac 24$.  Thus the probability that we have a success along this path is the product $\frac 35 \times \frac 24$.  And similarly for the second case.

Comment: A simpler way to understand that part of the calculation is to note that exactly two events comprise "second one green".  Namely $RG$ and $GG$.  It is easy to see that the first has probability $\frac 25\times \frac 34$ and the second has probability $\frac 35\times \frac 24$ and the two add to $\frac 35$.

Comment: Thank you. One more quick question. P(A or B) is actually giving the probability of getting A or B, including the probability that we get A and B, correct? So if I wanted to figure out P(A or B, excluding times when A and B occur) wouldn't I use P(A) + P(B) - 2 * P(A and B) ? I think this because the subtraction of P(A and B) only accounts for the fact P(A and B) has already been counted, so subtracting twice that should remove P(A and B) entirely, yes?

Comment: Usually in English people use "or" to mean what you say (that is, it includes both.).  Sometimes in math people want "or" to mean one or the other but not both...in such cases it is always a good idea to clarify your meaning.  Here, I took it to mean what you said.  To do your problem with the "exclusive or" just add the probabilities of the two events $GR,RG$.